# How could I add variables according to the length of the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that the values ​​range from A to Z, which I want to convert to variables that depend on the input data, for example:

enter the data

362,232,113 and this becomes an array of a length of 3 unit.

so I want to assign the name of a variable depending on the length of the input array but when executing the code, it assigns the array index well, but that same index executes the length of the input array and does not assign the variables as I would like it to.
in fact when executing this happens:

(3) 326
showing that the matrix was correctly divided but the same index was executed 3 times, in summary what I want is to be executed as follows:

"A = 326" "B = 232" "C = 113"

In advance I thank you for your help

```js
var asignLetter = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","Z","X","Y","Z"];

matrix =[326,232,113];

function divide(){
    xyz = matrix.split(",");
    console.log(matrix);
    for(var i = 0;i < xyz.length; i++){
        window[assignLetter[i]] = xyz[i];
        console.log(A); //(2) 326

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Setting global properties like this is very questionable. Why not use an object with string keys? Can you [provide more context about what you're trying to achieve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo `assignLetter` instead of `asignLetter` ( two `s` ) and you need to pass a `string` to your function for it to work :

```js
var assignLetter = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","Z","X","Y","Z"];

divide("326,232,113")// input data

function divide(matrix){
    xyz = matrix.split(",");
    for(var i = 0;i < xyz.length; i++){
        window[assignLetter[i]] = xyz[i];
    }
}

console.log({A,B,C});
```

You should avoid creating global variabels like that, have them in an object instead

```js
var assignLetter = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","Z","X","Y","Z"];

var myVars = {};

divide("326,232,113")// input data

function divide(matrix){
    xyz = matrix.split(",");
    for(var i = 0;i < xyz.length; i++){
        myVars[assignLetter[i]] = xyz[i];
    }
}

console.log(myVars);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to pass the parameters 326,232,113 as a whole string. You're passing them as parameters wrong.

So just do the same thing you're doing but like this: divide("326,232,113")